# Discrete space and space with non-trivial convergent sequence cannot be homeomorphic

Tags: general-topology, proof-writing

I found a claim that discrete space and space with non-trivial convergent sequence cannot be homeomorphic. Can someone explain why this is?

Here's what I think:

Let $(X, \mathfrak{T})$ be a discrete space which means singletons are open, and $(Y, \mathfrak{J})$ be a space with non-trivial convergent sequence.

Then let $(y_n)$  be that non-trivial convergent sequence, and $y_n \to y$, where $y$ is the limit of $(y_n)$. Then claim $\{y\}$ is closed $\leftarrow$ I'm not sure how to prove this. Please help.

Comment: Put it in your luggage the formally false statement that homeomorphic spaces are "the same". In spite of the fact that it is not true, it is very very handsome.

Comment: @drhab Sorry I don't quite understand

Comment: You are asked to prove that a homeomorphism can not exist between a space equipped with discrete topology and one with non-trivial convergent sequences. Realizing that homeomorphic spaces are practically "the same" this can be translated into: prove that a space equipped with discrete topology has no non-trivial sequences. This is an example of the fruits of this way of thinking.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If $X$ has discrete topology and $h:X\to Y$ is a homeomorphism then it can be shown easily that also $Y$ has discrete topology. After this step it is enough to prove that in discrete topology non-trivial convergent sequences do not exist.

---

If the topology is discrete then $\{y\}$ is an open set.

So if $y_n\to y$ then $y_n\in\{y\}$ or equivalently $y_n=y$ for $n$ large enough.

So the sequence is convergent on a trivial way.

Apparantly **all** convergent sequences in discrete space are convergent on a trivial way.

Answer (score 2):

Proving that $\{y\}$ is closed will not help you, because in the discrete space, all singletons are closed.

What you need to show is that there can be no homeomorphism between the two spaces. To do that, I would perform two steps:

1. Show that if $f:Y\to X$ is a homeomorphism and $(y_n)$ is a convergent sequence, then $(f(y_n))$ is a convergent sequence.
2. Show that if $X$ is a discrete space and $(x_n)$ is a non-trivial sequence, then it is not a convergent sequence (or, equivalently, show that if $(x_n)$ is a convergent sequence, then it is trivial from some point on).

Both of these steps are fairly simple, and it is good practice for you to see how the two statements together mean that a homeomorphism between $X$ and $Y$ cannot exist.

Answer (score 2):

In $X$ all points have a singleton neighborhood whereas in $Y$ there is a point $\xi$ having no such neighborhood.

Answer (score 0):

Let $X$ be a discrete space and $Y$ be a space with nontrivial convergent sequence $y_n \to y$ in $Y$. The sequence is nontrivial means it is not constant after any $n \in \mathbb{N}$. Now suppose $Y$ is homeomorphic to $X$. Then there exists a function $f : X \to Y$ which is a homeomorphism. In order to get the contradiction, we need only to use that $f$ is one one and continuous. Since $f$ is continuous and $y_n \to y$ in $Y$, we have $f(y_n) \to f(y)$ in $X$. But one one image of a nontrivial sequence is nontrivial and hence $\{f(y_n)\}$ is a nontrivial sequence in $X$. So, it does not converge. Thus $f$ is not continuous and hence it is not a homeomorphism.

Answer (score 0):

Although the answers already given are sufficient, I'd like to add this : If $Y$ is not discrete   then there is no continuous injective $f:Y\to X$ to any discrete space $X.$

Take $U\subset Y$ with $U\ne$ Cl$_Y(U)$ and take $y\in $Cl$_Y(U)$ \ $U .$ Let $f:Y\to X$ be continuous.

Since $y\in Cl_Y(U)$ we have $f(y)\in Cl_X  \{f(u):u\in U\}$ because $f$ is continuous. But $Cl_X\{f(u):u\in U\}=\{f(u):u\in U\}$ so $f(y)=f(u)$ for some $u\in U,$ and $f$ is not 1-to-1.